# IntelliJ and sharing the project files in VCS

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and after very long time I was not able to figure out, what IntelliJ specific files should not or should not be in VCS. I have a project which has different running configurations among various commits, so everytime when I checkout the project from different branch, I have to adjust the Running/Debug configurations. Jetbrains does not recommend to put workspace.xml in VCS because it could contain user-specific settings, however this information about Run/Debug configurations IS stored here! It would be 10x smarter to store in IML file (IntelliJ project file). How do you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the run configuration dialog (top right corner), there is the "Share" checkbox. If you mark a run configuration as shared, it will be stored in a separate file under .idea and not in workspace.xml, and you'll be able to add it to the version control system normally.

Comment: And compiler settings? I have some directories excluded from compiling process.

Comment: The excluded directories are stored in .idea/compiler.xml which is intended to be shared through the VCS.